# Mobile Push SDK creating iOS test users as OPTED OUT

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

As stated, the SFMC Mobile Push iOS SDK is creating test users in an OPTOUT status.  Meaning the OPTOUT Date is same as the create date, and there is no OPTIN date.

I found this post on here (on how to fix) that looked promising, but it does not seem to be our issue.

*"if you're having issues with the opted-in status of a device or devices then you should verify the APNS certificate you have registered with the Marketing Cloud servers. The most common issue (99% of the time) is the wrong certificate being uploaded to your application in the Marketing Cloud.*"

Anyone else know what else could be our issue?

Thank you!
Patrick

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: I have been a member for years. this is not my first post or comment.  Is your comment preventing people from seeing my question?  @identigral